# html form as an iFrame in different pages with context

Tags: html, forms, mobile, iframe

I am making an event registration form that I hope to load into all different kinds of event pages using an iframe and a url id (context). The id will display a relevant image before the form and then select the appropriate event from a drop down menu, which is working.

It's for desktop and mobile, using html, css and javascript then running a php script on submit.

Is an iFrame the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [modals](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) from [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/). It is the best choice. This is much more safer compared to iframe as well

Comment: Anywhere I can find info on the dangers of iFrames? We're going ahead with them as we can use them within an iPhone app without having to wait for approval after making changes.

Comment: XSS is possible. I guess you could close the holes